# I have a data frame that I’d like to filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

On the column that I’d like to filter, the column contains data from two different sources. I’d like to normalize this data. We collected some data a certain way and the other rows of data contain data that was collected another way. There are rows that contain 1.2 2.3 3.4 and nothing over 5. I would like to multiply these numbers by 1,000 to match up with the others and remove the comma from the numbers above 1,000.

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.641 |
| 2 | 1.548 |
| 3 | 1,807.000 |
| 4 | 1,759.000 |

Comment: How is your table stored? csv, text file, pandas dataframe?

Comment: Assuming you're showing us a DataFrame, what is the dtype of that column?

Comment: @ManlaiA it should just be 1,807

Comment: @user23952 to answer your question, we store the table with a DataFrame

Comment: @KarlKnechtel float64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to filter some rows (`col2 < 5`), apply a transformation (`col2 * 1000`) then remove something (`,`).

`df.loc[df['col2']<=5,'col2'] = df['col2']*1000`

Next would be to remove the comma but if you know all the values in col2 are whole numbers (no decimals) then I think you can just

`df['col2'] = int(df['col2'])`

But its safer to apply a replace but only if the values are string (if not, `df['col2'] = str(df['col2'])`)

Then you can apply the following:

`df['col'2'] = df['col2'].str.replace(',','')`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a boolean mask on whether `'col2'` contains a comma or not. If it contains a comma, remove the comma. For numbers with no comma, multiply it by 1000:

```
mask = df['col2'].str.contains(',')
df.loc[mask, 'col2'] = df.loc[mask, 'col2'].str.replace(',','')
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype(float)
df.loc[~mask, 'col2'] *= 1000
```

Output:

```
   col1    col2
0     1  1641.0
1     2  1548.0
2     3  1807.0
3     4  1759.0
```

Answer (score 1):

One other thing I thought about was the type mixing in Python. Based on what you have above, my guess is either you have `col2` as string or float. If string, then go through the replace method to get rid of the string. If float, then you shouldn't need to replace the comma (that may be how Python shows thousands and millions but I can't remember specifics).

Run `print(df.dtypes)` to check.

Answer (score 0):

I have only tried one solution of those given.

Float64. What you talked about is accurate @fmarz10. I wanted to filter the rows and apply a transformation, then remove something. This first row of code works perfect, it just worked.

`df.loc[df[‘col2’]<=5,’col2’] = df[‘col2’]*1000`

I did, however, refrain from using the second suggestion to as some numbers are not just whole numbers and contain values at least two places into the decimal. To complete it, I did something like this and it looks good from just scanning the first few rows.

`df[‘col’2’] = df[‘col2’].replace(‘,’,’’)`

vs the original suggestion:

`df[‘col’2’] = df[‘col2’].str.replace(‘,’,’’)`

NOTE: This works, but this is weekly data, and each row is a week’s worth of data and there are about 15,000 rows, so I need to just graze a few before making an assessment, but the first few look good.

Comment: @ManlaiA That's correct it would be a crazy outlier. I bumped the limit up to 15, this is a good limit for our value being collected bc it would be impossible. Thank you for brining this up.